# How can I write reusable @property getters/setters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to not repeat definitions for getters/setters that are structurally the same using the @property decorator. An Example:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,length):
        self.length=length
    # length
    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length

    @length.setter
    def length(self, val):
        # do some checks here (e.g. for units, etc.) (same as in the class below)
        self._length = val


class bar:
    def __init__(self,width):
        self.width=width
    # width
    @property
    def width(self):
        return self._width

    @width.setter
    def width(self, val):
        # do some checks here (e.g. for units, etc.)(same as in the class above)
        self._width = val
```

The attributes width in class bar and length in class foo have structurally the same setters so I want to define a generic setter I can apply for these attributes. 
However, I am not sure how to achieve the desired behaviour? Maybe with second degree decorators?

Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It is tedious unfortunately to do it this way, but it is recommended for a few reasons: it's explicit, so people reading your code know exactly what's going on; and it works with inheritance which can be a surprisingly tricky thing to get right.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid code duplication best way is to write a class method in say foo and then call it in bar and foo. I meant  just for the checking units part in the setter. or make it a global check function.

Comment: Yes I started out doing it with the duplicates, but when you want to change something at some point in the future you are in trouble. Therefore, I was wondering whether there is a standard solution. After all, I am still learning Python and looking for good ways to solve these problems when they appear =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I thought I could give an update on what I ended up with. So the reason why I was looking for a solution like this was also, that I wanted to incorporate unit-tracking for my attributes, via their setters and be able to parse unit-value data.

```
import varCheck #modified parsing functions for my specific data
from astropy import units as u
########################################################################################
# length
########################################################################################
def make_length(internalVarName, description):
    def _get_length(self):
        return getattr(self, internalVarName)

    def _set_length(self, val):
        setattr(self, internalVarName, varCheck.valueUnitPair(val))
        # assert that the unit is actually of type length e.g. 'm' by
        # calling the astropy unit conversion function within varCheck.valueUnitPair
        # NOTE: this will not convert the unit specified in the input!
        assert getattr(
            self, internalVarName).to(u.m).unit, "val not of type 'length'!"

    def _del_length(self):
        del self.__dict__[internalVarName]

    return property(_get_length, _set_length, _del_length, str(description))



class foo:
    length = make_length('_length', 'the yardstick')

def __init__(self,length):
    self.length = length
```

To me this solution seems fairly neat, but maybe I am overseeing something...
If you have any comments on that, feel free to comment :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe You could use python descriptor protocol to achieve what You want

```
class Unit(object):
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # put validation here
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            # allow access to the descriptor as class attribute
            return self
        return instance.__dict__.get(self.name)


class Container:
    length = Unit()
    width = Unit()

    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 100
        self.width = 200


def main():
    t = Container()
    print(t.length)
    print(t.width)
    t.length = 3
    t.width = 15
    print(t.length)
    print(t.width)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I think that will do the trick. I will have to have a look at it in my work's context :)

Comment: –1 this is wrong usage of descriptor protocol (leak of state).  If you put `t1 = Foo(10)` and then `t2 = Foo(20)` then you will see that `t1.length` is now incorrect value.

Comment: You are right @wim and fixed code example. In general my idea was to point that there is such solution, that could help :)

Comment: Yes - looks better now.  I agree that using descriptors is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately `@property` just returns an object implementing the descriptor protocol, so you could easily implement such a thing like this:

```
class ReusableProperty:
   def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
       self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
       return obj.__dict__.get(self.name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
       # do tests
       obj.__dict__[self.name] = value

class Foo:
    bar = ReusableProperty()

f = Foo()
print(f.bar)
f.bar = 'baz'
print(f.bar)
```

This is a minimal example, you'll want to familiarise yourself with the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) and perhaps decorators to make this more complete and perhaps dress this up in more reusable ways, but as long as you set the property to an object implementing `__get__` and `__set__`, you can customise this to your liking. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330273/476 for a good overview.

Note that `__set_name__` is only available since Python 3.6; in older versions you'd need to explicitly pass the name through `__init__`, like `bar = ReusableProperty('bar')`.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the problem in the meantime in a similar fashion, but still using the property class.